# What join do I use?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Hello I have 1 database with the following 3 tables:

```
Classroom ///
Student ///
ClassroomToStudent
```

A student can have multiple classrooms
A classroom can have multiple students

```
Classroom:

classroomid (primary key)
classroomnumber


Student:

studentid (primary key)
studentName


ClassroomToStudent:

ctsid (primary key)
studentid
classroomid
```

A student called john with an id of 1, and a classroom with number 10 with an id of 1 excist. The ClassroomToStudent table has a ctsid of 1, a studentid of 1 and a classroom id of 1.

These are related.
So, now that the ClassroomToStudent table has 1 row with 3 values, I want to display the name of the student that matches the name of the classroom. So john has a classroom with the number of 10. I want to display this in a HTML table but I don't know what join to use. I hope someone can hepl me out with this.

Comment: "what join to use" --- have you made a research of available types?

Comment: Yea I was thinking about an inner-join but I was not sure.

Comment: "the name of the student that matches the name of the classroom" There's a classroom "John"?

Comment: Just thought I'd mention, that you don't need the column `ctsid` in your `ClassroomToStudent` table. You can make `studentid` and `classroomid` a composite primary key.

Comment: The name of the student that matches the classroomnumber* (my bad)

Comment: As a hint: in `ClassroomToStudent` you don't need an explicit column `ctsid` for putting a primary key on it. Your primary key would be the combination of `studentid` and `classroomid`. This ways you would have the nice side effect that no student can be assigned to the same classroom more than one time. I'd go that far to say that no n:m table needs an `id`-column.

Comment: @Niek Jonkman: "Yea I was thinking about an inner-join but I was not sure." --- so why haven't you tried to see if it solves your issue?

Comment: @Joshua - I think that's going a little too far, but it's fine as broad principle.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.studentName, c.classroomnumber
FROM Student AS s
LEFT JOIN ClassroomToStudent AS cs
ON s.studentid = cs.studentid
LEFT JOIN Classroom AS c
ON c.classroomid = cs.classroomid
```

Give that a try, then loop the query (`while ($databaseClass->fetch($query)`), while echoing the results as you'd like :)

Comment: @ChrisH: it depends not a db size, but on a desired result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.studentName
FROM Classroom AS c
LEFT JOIN ClasroomToStudent AS cs
ON c.classroomid = cs.classroomid
LEFT JOIN Student AS s
ON cs.studentid = s.studentid
WHERE c.classroomnumber = x // x is a class number you're looking for
```

This sql gives You students names wchich are connected to class with number x